Macbook: CapsLock remapping to Command in system and Right Command remapping to Control in iTerm2 makes transitive remapping, workaround?
I am setting up my new Macbook system. I have remapped CapsLock key to be Command in system settings. Then I remapped Right Command to be Control in iTerm2 settings.
It seems that this setup transitively remapped CapsLock -> Control for iTerm2. Though when i remap Left Command to Control everything works as expected: CapsLock works as Command and Left Command works as Control. I therefore assume that the problem is that remapping CapsLock to Command in system settings remaps it to Right Command.  It seems that this behaviour started since MacOS Sonoma (14).
Is it possible to make system settings remap CapsLock to Left Command specifically to work around this issue in some other way?

The problem did indeed come down to system remapping CapsLock to some weird key. I found this question, which helped me see which key CapsLock was remapped to (by using defaults -currentHost read -g). On the system, where everything worked fine it looked like this:
"com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.1452-833-0" =     (
            {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771299;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771129;
    }
);

On my newer system it looked like this:
"com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.0-0-0" =     (
            {
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst = 30064771303;
        HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc = 30064771129;
    }
);

So I changed the dst modifier to 30064771299 with this command:
defaults -currentHost write -g com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.0-0-0 -array '<dict><key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc</key><integer>30064771129</integer><key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst</key><integer>30064771299</integer></dict>'

After system reboot everything works as expected (I am able to use CapsLock as Command in iTerm2 and no transitive remapping applies).
Key ids can be found in this apple manual. They are basically a concatenation of 7000000 and code from the table in hex. So CapsLock key is 0x70000001B which is 30064771099.
